# How to Create Page for Search?

Tags: search, http-status-code-404, html

I Put the Database Search for my Plugin.
But When Searching gives 404 Error !

What do I do to fix 404 Error?

My Code is:

```html
<?php
function qrn_search_code(){
 
 global $wpdb,$table_prefix;
 
 if($_POST['submit']) {
  if($_POST['search']) {
   
                    $search = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, code FROM ".$table_prefix."qrn_dessini WHERE code LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' ORDER BY ID DESC;");
   print_r($search);
                        
   
  }
 }

 <form  method="POST" id="searchform">
    <input  type="text" name="name" class="qr_search" placeholder="جستجوی کد محصول ...">
    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="qr_submit">
    </form>
}
add_shortcode('search_code','qrn_search_code');
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you have a beginning php tag at the end of your function, and also no ending:

```
<?php
}
add_shortcode('mysearch','search_code');
```

So I would try to change this to start:

```
}
<?php
add_shortcode('mysearch','search_code');
?>
```

Comment: No Problems. 
I added end tag - But it was not her problem? - after Click on Submit, Show 404 Error!

Comment: Search Link it is: http://localhost:8080/wp/sample-page/?name=201510001000&submit=Search

Comment: That link works only on a local network, indicated by the portion that says "localhost". BUT, if you'd like to test a website it's best to do it live (in my humble opinion). So try making a [link](http://000webhost.com) account and creating a domain.

Comment: When I use the search I doesn't give me a 404 error. It was difficult since I don't speak the language but when I searched for a word in any of the other pages it actually listed that page's content and all the others as well. So what you have uploaded to your site works perfectly in my opinion.

Comment: Search the database plugin and database plugin Show By table in page. How I can create a Page or show results for Search? Like WordPress!

Comment: in the if($_POST['submit']) is  no Problem But problem has in the if($_POST['search']) - Please check my code in the above.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found The problem.Thanks again